# How to build a BLE advertisement with the Bluez DBus API and Qt DBus

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to figure out the Bluez DBus API, and I'm having trouble understanding some of the concepts.

The most thorough Bluez examples I've seen have all used Python's `dbus-python` library. For example, [this python script](https://github.com/luetzel/bluez/blob/master/test/example-advertisement) demonstrates how to create a BLE advertisement. A lot of the content is in the `Advertisement` class, which extends `dbus.service.Object`. The `Advertisement` class implements a `GetAll` method (from the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` interface) and a `Release` method (from the `org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1` interface). In order to register that advertisement, it calls `RegisterAdvertisement` from the `org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1` interface.

I'm getting tripped up because I'm more used to Qt DBus, so I was thinking about what it would look like if the same thing was done using PyQt instead of `dbus-python`. I think the biggest hurdles are:

1. I can't figure out how the `Advertisement` class in the example would fit into the interface/adaptor model of Qt Dbus
2. In the example, the `Advertisement` class implements methods from two interfaces. I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104961/3684433), which implies that it can be done, but I don't think I fully understand the mechanics of it

So, in summary, if I wanted to re-implement this example with Qt DBus, what would the `Advertisement` class look like? Would it extend `QDBusAbstractAdaptor` or `QDBusAbstractInterface`? Would it contain one (or both) of those things? Or is there something else entirely that I'm missing?

## Edit:

Based on some info from @ukBaz, I dug a little deeper and tried a few more things, but I've come up empty so far. For reference, I have two scripts [in this github repo](https://github.com/maldata/qt-dbus-bluez). The `stock-example.py` script is pulled directly [from the Bluez source tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement?h=5.60). The `qt-example.py` script is my attempt at "translating" it to use QtDBus.

What I have found is that the stock script and the Qt script both work enough that I can see them advertising in [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) on my phone. However, the call to `RegisterAdvertisement` in the Qt app always times out:

```py
class BleAdManager(QDBusAbstractInterface):
    def __init__(self, dbus_obj_path, parent=None):
        self._ble_adapter_dbus_path = dbus_obj_path
        self._dbus_system_bus = QDBusConnection.systemBus()

        super().__init__("org.bluez",
                         self._ble_adapter_dbus_path,
                         "org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1",
                         self._dbus_system_bus,
                         parent)

    def RegisterAdvertisement(self, ad_path):
        print("Registering {0}...".format(ad_path))
        msg = self.call('RegisterAdvertisement', QDBusObjectPath(ad_path), {})
        print("Call returned.")
        reply = QDBusReply(msg)

        if reply.isValid():
            print("Valid")
            return reply.value()
        else:
            print(reply.error().message())
            return None
```

When I run this, it hangs on the `QDBusAbstractInterface.call()` for about 25 seconds, then spits out

```
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Since the stock script works, it can't be a security policy problem. Should the remote application send me a reply to `RegisterAdvertisement`? If not, how do I handle that gracefully with QtDBus (i.e., without it hanging and giving me an error)? If so, why wouldn't I get a response, and how should I attempt to debug?

Comment: Hey, I know this was two years ago, but I was running into a similar problem with the long wait then timeout. You need to make sure the event loop is running when you make the call to `RegisterAdvertisement` (or start it right after) because `RegisterAdvertisement` will query your object for it's properties, but the call will hang because you are waiting for the response from `RegisterAdvertisement`. I solved this by using an async method call.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the BlueZ Advertising D-Bus API is available at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/advertising-api.txt

The `org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1` is a D-Bus service that is published to the SystemBus and is responsible for providing the data for the advertisements. This published service can be at any D-Bus object path.

The `org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1` is a D-Bus client that, through `RegisterAdvertisement`, informs BlueZ what the `org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1` D-Bus object path is.

I have not used D-Bus in PyQt so I went looking for an example and found the following which seems to use DBus-Python:

https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_DBusIntegration

As a side note https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/ does say the following:

> New applications should use pydbus, txdbus or GDBus/QtDBus bindings

There is an example of using pydbus to create the advertisement at:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114130/121848

Comment: Thanks, @ukBaz! I think some of my problems *are* Qt-specific. I'm struggling to understand how a "D-Bus service" and "D-Bus client" map to Qt's adapters and interfaces.

Based on this, it seems like I need an adapter class to expose my advertisement object on the system bus, and then I need an interface class to talk to the advertising manager. However, the adapter seems to also need to implement the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` and `org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1` interfaces. Is that true, and if so, can a class inherit from or contain an adapter *and* two interfaces?